# Completar meses faltantes python - ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Tengo una tabla, la cual está compuesto de 3 columnas ( Date, Precio y Ref.)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intento completar los datos desde 2019-01-01 hasta 2022-03-31 con el valor del Precio = 0 **por referencia** con la siguiente linea de código:

```
`df = df.asfreq("M")`
```

El error que se presenta es el siguiente:

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

Lo que se desea lograr es tener es tener los 12 datos (1 año) de cada una de las referencias imputando los meses que hacen falta, por referencia así [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buen día, ¿El rango de fechas que deseas siempre va a ser el mismo (desde 2019-01-01 hasta 2022-03-31) o depende del `dataframe`? El método `asfreq()` toma como referencia el primer y último valor de tus datos y agrega los valores intermedios así que si tu primer elemento es 2019-10-01 no puede generar la fecha desde enero únicamente con los datos que tiene.

Comment: Lo que intento es armar una serie de tiempo, completando los datos faltantes con algún método de imputación. 

datos1 = datos.asfreq("MS")  - Me permite tener una serie continua desde la primer y última fecha de los datos , tal y como lo mencionas @HeytalePazguato